# How To Create Heroku App With Specific Region

Tags: django, heroku

please help me. I first tried to deploy an Django Site on Heroku with Free Plan, It went with default Region (US). And now I'm trying to deploy with Asia Tokyo Region, but I couldn't find a way to do it even I'm willing to goes with paid plan.
Many thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2):

If you list the available regions you will see what is available

```
$ heroku regions


ID         Location                 Runtime
─────────  ───────────────────────  ──────────────
eu         Europe                   Common Runtime
us         United States            Common Runtime
dublin     Dublin, Ireland          Private Spaces
frankfurt  Frankfurt, Germany       Private Spaces
oregon     Oregon, United States    Private Spaces
sydney     Sydney, Australia        Private Spaces
tokyo      Tokyo, Japan             Private Spaces
virginia   Virginia, United States  Private Spaces
```

Aside EU and US the other regions require [Private Spaces](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-private-spaces) which is quite expensive ($1000 p/month), see [pricing](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-private-spaces#pricing)

Answer (score 0):

To create an app in the Tokyo region, you could do it with on the Heroku CLI like this:

```
C:/>heroku create your-app-name --region=tokyo
```

As pointed out by Beppe C, you can list the available regions with:

```
C:/>heroku regions
```

The region ID is what you need to type after "--region=".